# Constructor injection cannot find symbol method inject members

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm working on an Android application which has dagger dependencies. When injecting class through constructor injection it's throwing an error that it cannot find symbol. If I provide the dependency through an `@Provides` method defined inside a module, everything works fine.

The code:

```
  public class SixthGenericTest {

        @Inject
        FirstTest firstTest;

        @Inject
        public SixthGenericTest()
        {
            Injection.create().getAppComponent().inject(this);
        }
        public String getData(){
            return firstTest.getTestName();
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = {FirstModule.class})
    public interface AppComponent {
        void inject(SixthGenericTest sixthGenericTest);

    }
```

and the error I got:

> Error:(19, 28) error: cannot find symbol method
>   injectMembers(MembersInjector,SixthGenericTest)

Comment: This happens to me when I upgrade from 2.13 to 2.15. So maybe try using version 2.13 instead of 2.15. I have no idea why 2.15 breaks my code that works with 2.14. Interesting is, that the error is in the generated code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade your dagger version

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.x'
  annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.x'
}
```

[Check last version here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.dagger/dagger)

Comment: Key - make sure all 'dagger' versions are the same. Make sure compile and annotationProcessor are using the same versions. My problem was one was 2.11 and another was 2.15.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to inject`Injection.create().getAppComponent().inject(this);` `@Inject` annotated constructeur is enough since it is automatically added to the graph, you may though add your scope above your class name

```
@Singleton
public class SixthGenericTest {

    FirstTest firstTest;

    @Inject
    public SixthGenericTest( FirstTest firstTest )
    {
        this.firstTest = firstTest;
    }

    public String getData()
    {
        return firstTest.getTestName();
    }
}
```

and remove from component:

```
 void inject(SixthGenericTest sixthGenericTest);
```

Comment: I want to inject this sixthGenericTest in other class

Comment: I want to provide this object to other classes also

Comment: That's the point! you can provide SixthGenericTest in other classes doing so! @Inject on constructeur mean "add me to the graph" like you would do in module classes with provides method

Comment: provides one i have already done but what i want with constructor injection is it possible or not

Comment: Is this something that is needed now with 2.15? Before 2.15 (2.13 i tested) i never got the error that @skyshine reports.